# How can solve this error "Uncaught TypeError: inputArgs[0].match is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication

When login first then immediatly show:-  "Uncaught TypeError: inputArgs[0].match is not a function" this error .

I'm using react-firebase-auth hook. when I try loging it login successfully .
my code like as=

```
import useSignInWithGoogle form react-firebase-hooks
const [signInWithGoogle, user, loading, error] =useSignInWithGoogle(auth);
if (user) {console.log(user)}
```

it show first 2 result like -UserCredentialImpl and then show:

> Uncaught TypeError: inputArgs[0].match is not a function

and the again show `UserCredentialImpl` and again:

> Uncaught TypeError: inputArgs[0].match is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.npm -g firebase-tools and npm firebase-tools or yarn add firebase-tools
2.do not console.log() directly to authState(auth) or useAuthState (auth) user

3.try to put it on condition

```
  const [signInWithGoogle, googleuser, googleloading, googleerror] =
useSignInWithGoogle(auth) if (googleuser) {
console.log(googleuser)};
```

or console.dir() instead of console.log()

Answer (score 1):

I'm also getting the same error! today. Alternatively, you can try a different browser like Mozila / Safari / Brave. Or you can use console.dir() instead of console.log(). Or you can you add a string before log like: console.log("data", user)

Answer (score 1):

i think you guys using react 18

use useEffect to console the user from useState

useEffect(()=>{

if (user) {console.log(user)}
},[])

100% will work,or else let me know i will suggest you one more method

Answer (score 1):

simple use console.dir(user) instead of console.log(user);

Answer (score 0):

Disable **React Developer Tools** and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me. I face the same problem.

```
useEffect(()=>{

      if (user) {console.log(user)} },[])
```

thank's @VAMagendran